# Terraform User TF_VAR not working nested module

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, devops, infrastructure-as-code

I'm working for a terraform provisioning modules for my infra. 
My structure is shown as below,

```
terra1
|
|---terra1.tf

main.tf
```

### main.tf

```
 module "terra_module" {
   source = "./terra1/"

  }
```

### terra1.tf

```
variable "PW" {}

output "data"  {
     value = "${var.PW}"
}
```

`terra1.tf` is in the child directory and it contains my module codes. When I call it via `main.tf` file so it give to me variable error .

```
 ##Command
 TF_VAR_PW=bar terraform apply
```

By the way, 
 If I run terra1 on it's own directory I did not get any error .

Problem : Use environment variable via module without assign it in every call (!!from module !! )

How Can I solve this problem ??

Thanks .

Answer (score 3):

In your modules, it can't know the environment variables you try to do via `TF_VAR_XXX`. you have to build a bridge to transfer it.

Here is the fix

```
variable "PW" {}

module "terra_module" {
  source = "./terra1/"

  PW = "${var.PW}"
}
```

I knew it is some annoying copy/paste job, but that's the way `terraform` works

If you want to get the output from this module, you need add another `output` (transfer it back)

So the full `main.tf` becomes to:

```
variable "PW" {}

module "terra_module" {
  source = "./terra1/"

  PW = "${var.PW}"
}

output "data" {
  value = "${module.terra_module.data}"
}
```

Then you will get:

```
$ TF_VAR_PW=bar terraform apply

Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

data = bar
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing to send varialbe from module. Yo can change your main.tf as:

```
module "terra_module" {
   source = "./terra1/"
   PW     = "someValue"
  }
```

Comment: wrong answer, the PO asks to get the variable's value from `TF_VAR_xxxx`. With your code to hard code the value, it will never work,